# How to read properties from Integration Test in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

My project structure looks like this:

[image: Project Structure in IntelliJ]

I have a `catalina.properties` in `src/testIntegration/resources` that gets output to `build/resources/testIntegration` folder. Running integration tests in Gradle from command line is fine, but running integration tests in IntelliJ gives me issue. After some playing around with the file locations, I found that IntelliJ is always looking for test resource file in `build/resources/test` folder. If I placed my test resources file in `build/resources/test` manually, then test runs smoothly.

Is there a way to configure IntelliJ to look for resources in `build/resources/testIntegration` when I'm running tests in `src/testIntegration/java`?

**EDIT**:

I also found that my test in `src/testIntegration/java` gets compiled to `build/classes/test` when I run in IntelliJ, which explains why it's looking for resources in `build/resources/test` though, but it should really be outputting to `build/classes/testIntegration`

Comment: Did you mark the directories in testIntegration as source and resource directories?

Comment: Yes I did, I just updated my question with a screenshot of my IntelliJ project structure.